# Error on displaying mySQL records in my REST API

Tags: raspbian, gpio, led, node.js, mysql

I would like to seek help on my REST API. I have finished constructed my basic REST API for my Raspberry PI and able to work now, thanks to you guys. Now I would like to display mySQL database records in a table with loop so it can always display new records but it failed and prompt an error which I have screenshot it down and uploaded.

**This is my led_rest_api.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var gpio = require('pi-gpio');
var app = express();
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http');

var now = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'user',
   password: 'password',
   database: 'sensor'
});

dateFormat(now);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3030);

var display = conn.query('SELECT * FROM sensorInfo');

var table = ('<tr><th>Sensor ID</th><th>Sensor</th><th>On Log Time</th><th>Off Log Time</th></tr>');

foreach (display as row) {
        table. =
       "<tr><td>". $row['sensorId'] . "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row['sensors'] . "</td>".
       "<td>". $row['onLogTime'] . "</td>".
            "<td>". $row['offLogTime'] ."</td></tr>";
    });

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   response.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
   response.write("<html>");
   response.write("<head>");
   response.write("<title><H1 align="center">Sensor REST API</H></title>");
   response.write("</head>");
   response.write("<body>");
   response.write("<table border=1>table</table>");
   response.write("</body>");
   response.write("</html>");
   response.end();
});

app.put('/:pin/1', function(req, res)
{
  var pin = req.params.pin;

  gpio.open(pin, 'output', function(err){
    if (pin === 7){
        //Set pin 7 high (1)
            gpio.write(7, 1, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(1, "Red LED", current_timestamp(), NULL)', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(7);
        });
        return gpio;
    } if (pin === 11){
        //Set pin 11 high (1)
            gpio.write(11, 1, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(2, "Blue LED", current_timestamp(), NULL)', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(11);
        });
        return gpio;
    } if (pin === 16){
        //Set pin 16 high (1)
            gpio.write(16, 1, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(3, "Green LED", current_timestamp(), NULL)', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(16);  
        });
        return gpio;
    }
  }
});

app.put('/:pin/0', function(req, res)
{
  var pin = req.params.pin;

  gpio.open(pin, 'output', function(err){
    if (pin === 7){
        //Set pin 7 low (0)
            gpio.write(7, 0, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(1, "Red LED", NULL, current_timestamp())', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(7);
        });
        return gpio;
    } if (pin === 11){
        //Set pin 11 low (0)
            gpio.write(11, 0, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(2, "Blue LED", NULL, current_timestamp())', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(11);
        });
        return gpio;
    } if (pin === 16){
        //Set pin 16 low (0)
            gpio.write(16, 0, function() 
        {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO sensor(sensorId, sensors, onLogTime, offLogTime) VALUES(3, "Green LED", NULL, current_timestamp())', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
                else res.send('success');
         });
                res.send(now);
                gpio.close(16);
        });
        return gpio;
    }
  }
});

server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
```

**This is the error screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: You asked a similar question yesterday, and got no comment. If others, like me, have no idea what a "LED REST API" is, how you have you have connected your LED, or even what language the code is written in. you are unlikely to get much help.

Comment: I connect my LED using gpio to Raspberry PI. I wrote the program language is node.js which also a java script.

Answer (score 1):

Your express server is listening on port 3030 and not 3000 so the URL would be `http://localhost:3030/7/1`.

When testing your API you should not "key" the URL into a browser as this causes a GET request. Use something like curl to make a POST request instead.

Also consider changing your API to use PUT since multiple requests for an on or off switch has the same effect as a single request, better matching the semantics of the HTTP verb PUT (which is idempotent).

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your gpio.write call

```
if (pin === 7){
    //Set pin 7 low (0)
    gpio.write(7, 0, function() 
    { 
            gpio.close(7);
        return gpio;
    } );    // <----
} if (pin === 11){
```